# PHP mail with ASCII characters in subject and from

Tags: php, html, email

i have some PHP code, which send a mail, and i need the subject to contain the ASCII code for Ø which is `&Oslash;` but if i just input it in my php scipt, it just send me `&Oslash;`and not Ø..
Mime is set along with charset..

```
$header = "Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-5589-1" . "\n"; <br />
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\n";
```

Comment: There is no 'Ø' character in ASCII. `&Oslash;` is not ASCII but a HTML named character entity reference. Such things are not usable in email headers; you need to encode non-ASCII characters according to RFC 2047 instead.

Comment: Okay, so how would i do that?

Comment: Everything is explained in the spec: read RFC-2047 and follow the references therein.

Comment: Okay, thanks.
I will try it later, and comment back, if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$newsubject='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';
```

Comment: No, this will still output &Oslash;se when i want it to output Øse

Comment: I'd suggest to [quoted-printable encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-encode.php) the header instead - then it's still readable even if the client doesn't support it.

Comment: By the client you mean the email client? it does support it, i can show and send it in the messege, just not as from or the subject, i don't know why..

Comment: @Jap: If the code in this answer returns in an email with a HTML entity in it, it must be because your `$subject` _already_ contains a HTML entity instead of a proper Ø. Email subject lines are never in HTML, so the string you start with must contain an actual Ø rather than an HTML encoding. You should then replace `UTF-8` in the `=?...?B?` prefix by whatever charset your PHP strings are in, which is probably one of ISO-8859-1 (note: not 5589), Windows-1252, or UTF-8 if you're in Denmark.

Comment: This helped on the subject, but what about the Header from:?

Comment: tHE HEADER tag from: that defines who the email is sent from. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to give it a header aswell as encode the subject, ive not tried it though...

```
$charset = "GB2312";
$subject = 'some chinese text'
$encoded_subject = "=?$charset?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?=\n" ;
$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset={$charset}\n";
```

Source for this hunch is [here](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/745913-how-send-subject-chinese-using-mail)

Comment: This is not chinese it is Danish.. I don't know it will work though, we use ISO-5589-1

Comment: No it did not work, infact it woulden't even send me the email

Answer (score 0):

$newsubject='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';

Was what helped me, just remember ÆØÅ in the original Subject